# How can I remove shadow of Button on Dialog? Why is the shadow shown?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I created a dialog and there is a button.

I want different style of button. So I made this file and applied to the background attribute of the button.

[image]
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/my_pink_color">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_line_border_dialogue"></item>
</ripple>
```

I don't know why it has shadow around the button. It has two buttons. And the second button doesn't have any thing. When I remove the second button, the shadow seems gone.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_ripple"
        android:text="Close"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/my_text_color"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_close2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_ripple"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Don't show this in 24hours"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/my_text_color"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I just apply `btn_line_border_dialogue.xml` without the ripple. It is the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/my_yellow" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/my_pink" />
</shape>
```

How can I remove this effect?

Comment: Try setting the elevation to 0dp: `android:elevation="0dp"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` inside your `Button` 
refer : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#Borderless
Or If you don't need `Button` particularly, use `TextView` instead

Answer (score 1):

try to set elevation t0 0 dp or you can use TextView or Layout instead of button.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_ripple"
        android:text="Close"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/my_text_color"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_close2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_ripple"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Don't show this in 24hours"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/my_text_color"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This can be also fixed by setting android:stateListAnimator="@null" globally in Resources\values\styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/NoShadowButton</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NoShadowButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Setting `android:stateListAnimator` is what did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

set the stateListAnimator on the button as = "@null" in the xml. It will remove the shadow from the button.